# tide-mode in org-edit-src-code

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, javascript

I want to activate tide-mode when using Javascript soruce code blocks,
following this it works well with indium:

https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages/ob-doc-js.html

But I want to use tide when editing the source code. if I activate the tide-mode, it seems to work, but the tide server is started. with other js frames. So this is a problem.

So how can Acchieve this automatically, or I need a something differente. in order to activate autocomplete, maybe indium autocomplete shopuld work